# Entity Framework Invalid column name on Navigation Property foreign key

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have two tables, JobRequest and WorkOrder. The Primary Key for JobRequest is a varchar field named RequestNumber. There is also a field, of the same name as the foreign key in the work order table. There is a 0 to 1 relationship between the tables on that field; when a job request can't be completed by the organic maintenance team, a work order is issued for another maintenance team.

The databases look a bit like:

JobRequest

```
ID        BIGINT       IDENTITY,
RequestNumber       VARCHAR(15)        NOT NULL,
...
```

WorkOrder

```
ID        BIGINT       IDENTITY,
WONumber            VARCHAR(25)        NOT NULL,
RequestNumber       VARCHAR(15)        NULL,
...
```

I have a model built, the context built and the database tables. I used a manual code first so I don't have any template or SDL files.

My models look like:

```
[Table("JobRequest")]
public partial class JobRequest
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public JobRequest()
    {
        AuditLogs = new HashSet<AuditLog>();
        AuthorizedUsers = new HashSet<AuthorizedUser>();
    }

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long? ID { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [StringLength(15)]
    [DisplayName("Request Number")]
    public string RequestNumber { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public virtual WorkOrder WorkOrder { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<AuditLog> AuditLogs { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<AuthorizedUser> AuthorizedUsers { get; set; }

    ...
```

And

```
[Table("WorkOrder")]
public partial class WorkOrder
{
    public WorkOrder()
    {
    }
    
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long? ID { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [StringLength(25)]
    [DisplayName("Work Order Number")]
    public string WONumber { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Required]
    [StringLength(15)]
    [DisplayName("Request Number")]
    public string RequestNumber { get; set; }
```

In the context I have this:

```
    ...
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<JobRequest>()
            .HasOptional(j => j.WorkOrder);
    }
    ...
```

I can easily update my JobRequest table. When I create a Work Order from the job request, I get the error **Invalid column name 'WorkOrders_RequestNumber'**.

What the heck have I done wrong?
Do I need to add a CSDL file?

If I do, can someone break it down GUMBY style? I had a sleep study last night and I'm running on bad coffee and adrenaline.

Edited to add Navigation properties and Fluent definition.

Edit 2 - I made the changes suggested by Ivan Stoev (https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138056/discussion-between-russel-madere-and-ivan-stoev). Now everything saves, but the RequestNumber does not save in the WorkOrder table. This breaks the relationship after the data is saved. Can I get a suggestion on persisting the RequestNumber?

Edit 3 - Looking at the SQL Server Profiler, I see the following insert statement.

```
exec sp_executesql N'INSERT [dbo].[WorkOrder]([WONumber], [Owner], [JobName], [SubContractNum], 
                                          [ContractAmount], [Fee], [Company], [Department], 
                                          [DisplayCompany], [StartDate], [CompletionDate], 
                                          [County], [Taxable], [PPBond], [Address], [City], 
                                          [State], [Zip], [Country], [RequestedBy], 
                                          [PurchAddress], [PurchCity], [PurchState], [PurchZip], 
                                          [PurchCounty], [PurchCountry], [DescriptionOfWork], 
                                          [EntryUser], [EntryDate], [LastChangedBy], [LastChanged], 
                                          [ContractType], [Revision], [PrintURL], [RequestNumber])
VALUES (@0, NULL, @1, @2, @3, @4, @5, @6, @7, @8, @9, @10, @11, @12, @13, @14, @15, @16, 
    @17, @18, @19, @20, @21, @22, @23, @24, @25, @26, @27, @28, @29, @30, @31, @32, @33, 
    @34, NULL)
SELECT [ID]
FROM [dbo].[WorkOrder]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [WONumber] = @0'...
```

I left the schema and data specific information off of the statement.

I see here that the ForeignKey is being inserted as a NULL. How do I set the value of the foreign key?

Comment: I think `[Key]` is only used for denoting Primary Keys. I think there is a `[ForeignKey]` data annotation you can use, instead?

Comment: Please show the navigation properties for this relationship plus any related fluent configuration.

Comment: @BlackyWolf, If I remove the Key annotation, I get the same error, except it point to WorkOrders_ID.

Comment: @IvanStoev, added.

Comment: @BlackyWolf, I use Code First to a Database but am not using the wizard to generate an EDMX file. I will be using Navigation Properties, especially because I have a Job Request log that needs to display any work orders sent to other crews, This log is used to track budget considerations.

Comment: As an FYI, this is a legacy system that I am converting from Web Forms to Entity Framework and MVC.

Comment: What is the PK of WorkOrder table?

Comment: WONumber is the primary key.

Comment: There are a couple wrong attributes. But the real problem is that EF does not support correctly such relationship. You should set up it as `one-to-many` from `JobRequest` to `WorkOrder` and map `WorkOrder.RequestNumber` as FK.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138056/discussion-between-russel-madere-and-ivan-stoev).

Comment: @IvanStoev, I could use some advice on my latest issues. They are related to this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following design represents the provided sample database schema:

*Model:*

```
[Table("JobRequest")]
public partial class JobRequest
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long? ID { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [StringLength(15)]
    [DisplayName("Request Number")]
    public string RequestNumber { get; set; }

    public virtual WorkOrder WorkOrder { get; set; }
}

[Table("WorkOrder")]
public partial class WorkOrder
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long? ID { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [StringLength(25)]
    [DisplayName("Work Order Number")]
    public string WONumber { get; set; }
    public virtual JobRequest JobRequest { get; set; }
}
```

*Configuration:*

```
modelBuilder.Entity<JobRequest>()
    .HasOptional(e => e.WorkOrder)
    .WithOptionalPrincipal(e => e.JobRequest)
    .Map(m => m.MapKey("RequestNumber"));
```

*Some operations:*

1. Add new JobRequest w/o WorkOrder:

```
var jobRequest = new JobRequest { RequestNumber = "RN1" };
db.JobRequests.Add(jobRequest);
db.SaveChanges();
```

2. Add new WorkOrder w/o JobRequest:

```
var workOrder = new WorkOrder { WONumber = "WON1" };
db.WorkOrders.Add(workOrder);
db.SaveChanges();
```

3. Add new JobRequest and WorkOrder (linked together):

```
var workOrder = new WorkOrder { WONumber = "WON2" };
var jobRequest = new JobRequest { RequestNumber = "RN2" };
workOrder.JobRequest = jobRequest;
db.WorkOrders.Add(workOrder);
db.SaveChanges();
```

or alternatively

```
var workOrder = new WorkOrder { WONumber = "WON3" };
var jobRequest = new JobRequest { RequestNumber = "RN3" };
jobRequest.WorkOrder = workOrder;
db.JobRequests.Add(jobRequest);
db.SaveChanges();
```

4. Associate existing WorkOrder with existing JobRequest:

```
var workOrder = db.WorkOrders.Include(e => e.JobRequest).First(e => e.WONumber == "WON1");
var jobRequest = db.JobRequests.Include(e => e.WorkOrder).First(e => e.RequestNumber == "RN1");
workOrder.JobRequest = jobRequest;
db.SaveChanges();
```

or alternatively

```
var workOrder = db.WorkOrders.Include(e => e.JobRequest).First(e => e.WONumber == "WON1");
var jobRequest = db.JobRequests.Include(e => e.WorkOrder).First(e => e.RequestNumber == "RN1");
jobRequest.WorkOrder = workOrder;
db.SaveChanges();
```

5. Disassociate existing WorkOrder and JobRequest:

```
var jobRequest = db.JobRequests.Include(e => e.WorkOrder).First(e => e.RequestNumber == "RN2");
jobRequest.WorkOrder = null;
db.SaveChanges();
```

```
or alternatively
```

```
var workOrder = db.WorkOrders.Include(e => e.JobRequest).First(e => e.WONumber == "WON3");
workOrder.JobRequest = null;
db.SaveChanges();
```

All these operations work as expected and manage/persist the hidden (shadow) `WorkOrder.RequestNumber` property indirectly through navigation properties.

Note that operations on disconnected entities require special handling. If you have issues with correctly implementing disconnected entity modifications, you can create another post and provide the concrete details.